# SQLite.TableQuery Member access failed to compile expression

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

Getting SQLite.TableQuery Member access failed to compile expression, while registering  Async Table query

`public AsyncTableQuery<AppStateEvent> AppStateEvents => this.Table<AppStateEvent>();`

i have also checked issues from others and updated to SQLConnection(path,false), **deleted** any *DateTime* column in table still getting the same error.

PS: Am Using [Shiny for Xamarin](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny) the issue is only on Android, iOS works fine!

Comment: For this issue, try to add **ToList()** to the Table result: `this.Table<AppStateEvent>().ToList()`.  Here is the similar issue you can refer to: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/535#issuecomment-431642665

Comment: this is an SQLiteAsyncConnection so ToList() wont work, it has ToListAsync() but can  not cast to AsyncTableQuery.

Comment: Does 'this' represent the SQLiteAsyncConnection object? Could you post more details about the code?